# Filtering RecyclerView item (City) after getting json API

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

So, my app has successfully

1) Identified user's location (GPS Coordinates)

2) Passed these coordinates to an API and retrieved location specific data with retrofit.

3) Populated data to Recyclerview.

4) Implemented search functionality for user to filter the recyclerview as desired.  For example, user can search for "pizza" and shrink their results from the initial 300 to the 20 that contain the String "pizza".

Lastly, I want to give the user the ability to filter by City name.  I want to provide the user with the list of Cities that are generated from the recycleview list.  Of course, the list would change each time based on users initial search criteria.  How can I get the City list, which is one of the item fields retrieved from the API?

The "city" filter can be done before, after, or in place of the other filter.  in other words, if I can only do one, that's OK, then I would just do the "city" filter and not offer the wildcard filter.

Any help is appreciated, even if it is just a high level view of what needs to be done.  I guess first and foremost, I need to know how to get that list.  My limited knowledge of the nuts and bolts of how recyclerview actually works tells me this might not be available.

Comment: You can make an API request again if they support multi-filters. Otherwise you'll have put some condition in recycler view's onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Api> call, Response<Api> response) {

            Api api = response.body();

            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(api.getDetails()));

            //get city string array
            String[] sa_cities = new String[data.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < sa_cities.length; i++) {
                sa_cities[i] = data.get(i).getLocation();
            }

            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Api> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
```